# ROR Multiple radio button sets with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, radio-group

I am trying to code multiple radio buttons groups that has same name. my model looks as follows: 
**Survey
Survey Questions
Survey choices
Survey Response**

My survey response page displays question and choices from models and only saved question id and answer id.

I have multiple question that have radio button groups. they all act as one big group as they all have same name.

```
<% @survey_questions.each do |question| %>

    <p><%= question.question_content %></p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :survey_question_id, value: question.id %>

    <% if question.answer_type == "Text Field" %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :answer %>
        <%= f.text_area :answer, id: :survey_response_answer %>
      </div><br />
  <% else %>
    <% question.survey_answers.each do |answer| %>
      <%= f.radio_button_tag("survey_answer_id_#{question.id}", answer.id) %>
      <%= f.label_tag("survey_answer_id_#{question.id}", answer.answer_content) %><br />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I need something that can distinguish my radio buttons groups and can be saved as **survey_answer_id**